# My Ubuntu boots to a terminal session not a desktop

Tags: 18.04, lenovo

I am having problems while starting PC. I had done nothing but when I open it it shows a screen -

(The screen is black)

It has written on it:

```
Ubuntu 18.04.5 lts harshit-lenovo-ideapad-100-15IBY tty1
Harshit-lenovo-ideapad-100-15IBY login:
```

And when you login it shows:

```
Last login: Tue Sep 1 11:04:27 IST 2020 on tty1 

Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-42-generic x86_64)

*Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com

*Management: https://landscape.canonical.com

*Support: https://Ubuntu.com/advantage

*Canonical livepatch is available for installation. 
- Reduce system reboots and improve Kernel security. Activate at: 
Https://ubuntu.com/livepatch

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

Failed to connect to https:// changelings.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts. Check your internet connection or proxy settings 

Your hardware enablement stack (HWE) is supported until April 2023.

Harshit@harshit-lenovo-ideapad-100-15IBY:~$
```

Comment: Try `startx` after logging in.

Comment: So your system did boot, if you can log in. Only it boot to text mode and did not start a graphical session. So please change the title of your question appropriately.

Comment: You installed the server version perhaps? Did you ever get a desktop?

Comment: Rinzwind I have downloaded the desktop version only

Comment: Raj but can you help me

Comment: I am a new man in Ubuntu world

Comment: Hi organic marble starts is not getting me into the old Ubuntu as I was using before the problem